# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isValid]

Tags: objective-c

can anyone tell me what may be the reason of crash.

> Application Specific Information:â€¨*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isValid]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3f4a80'

Answer (score 1):

You sent the selector `isValid` to an array, which doesn't respond to that message. That's all that can be said without seeing the code.

Comment: I don't find isValid method in apple documentation.

Comment: That's because `isValid` is something in your code. Why would it be in official documentation? Please edit your question so it's possible to help. // I say "your code", but from your comment, it seems more likely that you copied it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my case,

to solve it:

**Add -all_load to the other linker flags in your build settings.**

> -all_load forces the linker to load all object files from every archive it sees, even those without Objective-C code.

---

***more description:***

> The "selector not recognized" runtime exception occurs due to an issue between the implementation of standard UNIX static libraries, the linker and the dynamic nature of Objective-C. Objective-C does not define linker symbols for each function (or method, in Objective-C) - instead, linker symbols are only generated for each class. If you extend a pre-existing class with categories, the linker does not know to associate the object code of the core class implementation and the category implementation. This prevents objects created in the resulting application from responding to a selector that is defined in the category.

> To resolve this issue, the target linking against the static library must pass the -ObjC option to the linker. This flag causes the linker to load every object file in the library that defines an Objective-C class or category. While this option will typically result in a larger executable (due to additional object code loaded into the application), it will allow the successful creation of effective Objective-C static libraries that contain categories on existing classes. Follow these steps to pass -ObjC to the linker:

> In Xcode, double-click the target's name under "Targets"

> in the Project window.Choose the Build pane from the ensuing Info window.

> Scroll down to the Other Linker Flags build setting under the Linking collection and set its value to -ObjC.